# Is there a way to go directly to chat through commens?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I have noticed that when you are exchanging comments with someone under an answer, and reach a certain number of comments, you are opted to start a chat instead. Is it possible to initiate this right away? If not, could you make it possible?

My example of when this could be nice to have is this: I wrote a general answer to a question about Hibernate, and after some time someone asked a quite specific question in a comment underneath my answer. I would like to help out, but still it would be nice not to clutter my general answer with very specific comments. In this case I would have liked to just initiate a chat with the person asking right away, and then avoid a long comment conversation that really is quite irrelevant to the actual answer.

Comment: Reason for downvote would be nice..

Comment: Probably a duplicate yes. While I don't fully agree with the conclusion in the other question, it still gave me a possible solution to the problem with comments cluttering general answers: After things are resolved, if you don't deem the comments as relevant for the answer, delete your own comments and mark others for deletion. That way you can keep the comments section clean.